# Difference between OnPreferenceTreeClickListener vs OnPreferenceClickListener

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

What is the difference between `OnPreferenceTreeClickListener` method vs `OnPreferenceClickListener` method in **Android**?

Comment: Check this [Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener) && [onPreferenceTreeClick](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceManager.OnPreferenceTreeClickListener.html#onPreferenceTreeClick(android.support.v7.preference.Preference))

Comment: Thanks already did, but couldn't find anything good...